# How to combine two ranges (intertwining rather than concatenating) in sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have column A (100 names) and column B (6 names). I want to disperse column B equally inside rcolumn A. I know `={(A1:A);(B1:B)}` will concatenate the ranges together. But is there a ways to disperse range B equally inside A? So the 6 names will go at positions 1,20,40,60,80,100 (about).

Comment: Attach an example or sheet.

Comment: you really want to see 1 column with 100 values and another with 6?

Comment: it's not so much wanting to see it, it's that it's almost impossible to figureou t how to solve it in the abstract, without a sample provided, the people who help have to make their own sheet in order to figure it out.  The theory is that the onus to provide a sample to work from should be on the person asking the question.  Not just because it's cumbersome to make a lot of sample sheets that you might not ever use again, but also because it eliminates a lot of miscommunication, even if (as in this case) the question is pretty straightforward.  
See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:A,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A));B1:B,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A),1,1)*COUNTA(A1:A)/COUNTA(B1:B)},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=arrayformula({"List";query({A2:A,row(A2:A)-1;filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),sequence(max(if(B:B<>"",row(B:B)-1)),1,0,(max(if(A:A<>"",row(A:A)))-1)/(max(if(B:B<>"",row(B:B)-2))))},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2",1)})
```

[image]